# Vantage point tree question

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm stuck in understanding the 1993 vantage point tree paper: http://aidblab.cse.iitm.ac.in/cs625/vptree.pdf

It defines some things first:

> So if $x\in[0,1]$, then $P(x)$ is the probability of the surface of the sphere $S(p,x)$
>
> Let $(\mathcal{S},d,P)$ be a metric space with associated probability measure $P$, the combination is said to have the ZPS property if and only if: $P(S_\mathcal{S}(x,r))=0,\forall x\in \mathcal{S},r\ge 0$, where $S_\mathcal{S}(x,r) = \{y\in \mathcal{S}|d(y,x)=r\}$

Then it goes onto say

> The probability of a countable intersection of nested sets, is just the limit of the individual properties. This and ZPS then imply that about any $x\in [0, 1]$, there exists an interval of arbitrarily small probability.

I don't understand why this is implied, or why countable intersection of nested sets is used here. Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: ZPS implies that $P$ is a continuous (i.e. vanishing at points) measure on $[0,1]$.

For any point $x\in [0,1]$ we have $\{x\}=\bigcap([0,1]\cap (x-1/n,x+1/n))$.

Comment: Thanks never knew about that equality.